# how to get Responsible API calls for used Permissions?

Tags: android, api

Consider

`PackageInfo info1 = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkPath,PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);`

In this statement, by using `GET_PERMISSIONS` I can get the set of all permissions used in the application.

In the same way can i get the API calls?

Thank you. I am new to this android programming if it is a simple question please forgive

Comment: Define "api callss"? If you're referring to anything else that isn't either [directly or indirectly available from the `manifest`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html), then I'm pretty sure the answer is *no*.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot get the API calls by any easy method, and arguably not even by a hard method.

If you had access to the application's installed .apk (and at least on older Android versions you did), you could read through it for obvious invocations of platform functions.  (This is a form of "Static Analysis")

However, Java (and hence Dalvik) supports a mechanism called "reflection" which allows looking up and calling functions by name - a name that could be constructed at runtime by circuitous means, or user or network input.

Much of the actual functionality used for calling functionality in the system process is also ultimately performed by name, making another place where functionality not present in the static file could be added at runtime.

Finally, the native underlayers of Android (and likely the DVM as well) permit a  determined programmer to dynamically designate arbitrary "data" to be "code" and then execute it.

Comment: In few online static analyser website, they have listed the api calls . How is that possible?

Comment: Try any apk decompiler.  But don't disregard the serious, fundamental limitations of static analysis not capturing invocations only "constructed" at runtime.